# Ripple effect not working on IE

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, sass, material-design

I have a ripple class to add a ripple effect to any HTML element.

```css
.bh-ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.bh-ripple:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000 10%, transparent 10.01%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  transform: scale(10, 10);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity 1s
}

.bh-ripple:active:after {
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  opacity: .2;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<div class="bh-header-menu-ct bh-right">
  <div class="bh-user-menu bh-ripple">
    <div class="bh-user-avatar bh-color-300">
      <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="bh-user bh-color-500">UserName</div>
    <div class="bh-color-700">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ripple effect works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but has issues on IE 11. The effect isn't happening on the first click. I have to click on the edge of the div to see the effect.

Comment: Since code is being compiled by ng-cli, corresponding prefixes added.Still no luck.

Comment: This problem seems more specific to IE11, Its working on IE10 as well.